# QPlainTextEdit() ->setPlainText() keeps crashing

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to update a QPlainTextEdit() from either a button click, thread, etc. Somewhere from outside the MainThread and in Qt documentation it says it must used signals but I can't figure out how. If I try to do a CreateThread() or use a std::thread to update the

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...

    private slots:
        handleButtonClick();
        Thread();
    ...
    private:

    QPlainTextEdit *TextView;
}



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),             ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ...
    TextView = new QPlainTextEdit();
    TextView->setReadOnly(true);
    TextView->setCursorWidth(0);

    QPUshButton *UpdateButton = new QPushButton();


            connect(UpdateButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(handleButtonClick()));

    ....
}


MainWindow::handleButtonClick()
{
    // eventually this will cause a crash, usually not imemdiately
    TextView->insertPlainText("test");  
}

MainWindow::Thread()
{
    TextView->insertPlainText("test");  
}
```

So as you can see, I want a way to update this QPlainTextEdit from outside the main thread without crashes. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: What's not verifiable about that?

Comment: It is verifiable.

Comment: verifiable implies that I can copy your code and reproduce your same error but your code is not.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to do UI opeations like updating the text of a QTextEdit from outside the main thread. The solution to this is emitting a signal from the non-main thread, and have it connected to a slot in the main thread which does the UI work.